# How to avoid default text issue in Custom Spinner Android?

Tags: android, spinner, adapter

i have done custom spinner with custom adapter in it but getting some default text everytime how to avoid this issue everytime it should only display 0th position text on spinner:

```
CourseAdapter courseAdapter = new CourseAdapter(mContext);
customViewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(courseAdapter);
```

while CourseAdapter.java

```
public class CourseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  public static final String TAG=CourseAdapter.class.getName();
    List<String> courses =new ArrayList<>(); // code to get the courses ArrayList
    Context context;
    private void fillCourses()
    {
        for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
        {
           if(i == 0)
           {
               courses.add("Choose");
           }
            else
           {
               courses.add("courses:"+i);
           }
        }
    }
    public CourseAdapter(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        fillCourses();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return courses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return courses.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolderFilterItem viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "fillCourses size:" + courses.size());
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.layout_customspinner, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolderFilterItem();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewFilterItem);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxFilterItem);
            //store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            return convertView;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "convertview != null:" + courses.size());
            viewHolder = (ViewHolderFilterItem) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(courses != null && courses.size() > 0) {
            String itemText = courses.get(position);
            if (itemText != null) {
             viewHolder.textView.setText(itemText);
             viewHolder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
            if(position == 0)
            {
             viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolderFilterItem{
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox checkBox;}

}[![[why Filter item text with checkbox appearing ?][1]][1]
```

Comment: Have you tried `android:prompt="@string/spinner_header"` ?

Comment: what do you mean by `some default text` you are getting.

Comment: default text means ? @Erum

Comment: @AmitVaghela its not showing data from my passed listitem ... but showing my layout xml data ..... first time click UI data while in second time then it populate data why is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `courseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting `customViewHolder.spinner.setAdapter(courseAdapter);`

Hope this helps.